# Jade: mimick simple PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, pug

I am currently trying to convert a PHP file into a Jade file to decrease server load*, but have run into some issues with converting the main PHP function - the reason for which that the page is not a HTML file in the first place - into Jade.

The function simplifies the listing of "items", and accepts multiple arguments in order to populate the different parts of the HTML code.

```
<?php
 function item( $name, $category, $url, $color, $partner=NULL ) {
    # convert åäö -> aao (lower- and uppercase)
    $filename = preg_replace(array('/å/','/ä/','/ö/','/Å/','/Ä/','/Ö/', '/\s+/'), array('a','a','o','A','A','O', '-'), $name);
    $filename = strtolower($filename);
  ?>
  <div class="projekt__item item-<?php echo $filename ?>" style="background-color: <?php echo $color; ?>">
    <div class="item__logo item__logo--<?php echo $filename ?>"></div>

    <div class="item__figcaption">
      <span class="item__figtext">
        <?php echo $category; ?><br>
        <?php if ($partner) : ?>
          <br>
          <span class="item__figtext--sub">
            <strong>Partner: </strong> <?php echo $partner; ?>
          </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </span>
    </div>

    <a href="<?php echo $url ?>" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"></a>
  </div> <!-- /item -->
<?php } ?>
```

There are different components of the PHP code which I find difficult to replicate in Jade. These are:

- Give one of the passable a variables a default value (e.g. partner=NULL)
- Convert "åäö " into "aao_" for lower and uppercase letters
- use the variables passed into the mixin in the code without syntax errors

I have set up a [pen](http://codepen.io/LajmeX/pen/bdYvzK) containing my so progress so far (which isn't very much - it just throws me a couple of errors which does not help me)

If anyone could assist me with this it would be greatly appreciated.

**I am aware of that there are other means to decrease server load, and that caching should make this redundant. However, it is also a matter of learning jade for future reference, and I would very much like to solve this problem instead of just leaving it behind :)*

**Update:**
Thanks to @laggingreflex the problem has been solved. The final solution is seen below:

```
mixin item(name, category, url, color, partner)
  - var filename = name.replace(/å/g,'a').replace(/ä/g,'a').replace(/ö/g,'o').replace(/Å/g,'A').replace(/Ä/g,'A').replace(/Ö/g,'O').replace(/\s+/g,'-')
  - filename = filename.toLowerCase()

  div(class='projekt__item item-#{filename}' style="background-color: #{color};")
     div(class='item__logo item__logo--#{filename}')
     div.item__figcaption
       span.item__figtext
         | #{category}
         if (partner)
           br
           span.item__figtext--sub
             strong Partner: #{partner}
     a(href=url rel="nofollow" target="_blank")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's couple of mistakes in your [Jade syntax](http://jade-lang.com/reference)

When defining a mixin method you can't assign default values to arguments.

```
item(name, category, url, color, partner=NULL) // error
item(name, category, url, color, partner)
```

btw if you don't pass an argument it's `undefined` by default.

At some places you're not actually interpolating the values of the variables, but simply outputting the variable names as plain strings

```
span.item__figtext
  | category // will output the text "category"
  | #{category} // will output the value stored in the variable category
```

Semi-colons are not a part of the Jade syntax (* unless you're doing inline JavaScript)

```
+item( "Intern...", ... ); // error
+item( "Intern...", ... )
```

**Update** with couple more suggestions

When you want to assign variable values to an attribute you don't want to put them in quotes

```
a(href="url" //  will output <a href="url"
a(href=url   //  will output <a href="http://example.com"
```

When using a variable in a class name, you can't use the dot `.class` notation, so you want to define it as an attribute

```
div.item-filename    // will output <div class="item-filename"
div.item-#{filename} // will result in error
div(class="item-#{filename}" // this is what you want
```

As for PHP's `preg_replace`, `.replace` is the JavaScript's equivalent, although it doesn't support arrays so you have to chain them, and you have to specify the `/g` regex modifier specifically.

Also to inline JavaScript code inside Jade you want to begin it with a hyphen `-`

```
- var filename = name.replace(/å/g,'a').replace(/ä/g,'a').…
```

So this is what your completed Jade should look like

```
mixin item(name, category, url, color, partner)
  //- convert "åäö B C" -> "aao-b-c" (lower- and uppercase)
  - var filename = name.replace(/å/g,'a').replace(/ä/g,'a').replace(/ö/g,'o').replace(/Å/g,'A').replace(/Ä/g,'A').replace(/Ö/g,'O').replace(/\s+/g,'-')
  - filename = filename.toLowerCase()

  div(class='projekt__item item-#{filename}' style="background-color: #{color};") #{filename}
    div(class='item__logo item__logo--#{filename}')
    div.item__figcaption
      span.item__figtext
        | #{category}
        if (partner)
          br
          span.item__figtext--sub
            strong Partner: #{partner}
    a(href=url rel="nofollow" target="_blank")

+item( "Example Name 1 åäö", "Design & Utveckling", "http://www.example_url.com/", "#45c0ae", "Example Partner" )
+item( "Example Name 2", "Design & Utveckling", "http://www.example_url.com/", "#346b98" )
+item( "Example Name 3", "Design & Utveckling", "http://www.example_url.com/", "#8191b2", "Example Partner" )
+item( "Example Name 4", "Design & Utveckling", "http://www.example_url.com/", "#485230", "Example Partner" )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @laggingreflex! Your extensive answer is much appreciated! This helps me a great deal, especially the part with the interpolation of variables using #{variable}. 

I updated my code accordingly. However, my code still contains multiple syntax errors which I fail to get around.

Comment: @Wilhelmw checkout the edit. If you still get errors, please update your post with the exact errors and the latest Jade snippet that you're using.

Comment: Oh wow... Thank you **very** much for _all_ the help! This turned into a Jade syntax tutorial - and now I'm not getting any errors at all! Thank you for your patience and your sharing of knowledge @laggingreflex, it is much appreciated.